# Abstract Wave using CSS

Tags: html, css, background-image

Through inspecting the CSS code of a website with this background, I was unable to find an image reference. There however was plenty of CSS lines such as:

```
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 50% 0%, 50% 100%, color-stop(0%, #363291), color-stop(100%, #4742be));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(#363291, #4742be);
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(#363291, #4742be);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(#363291, #4742be);
background-image: linear-gradient(#363291, #4742be);
```

Background:
[image]

How could I reproduce this in CSS? If I cannot make it in CSS, what program(s) would I use to design something like this?

Comment: Use any image creating software. Whereas this may be *possible* with CSS, it is definitely **much more work than it's worth**. It'd perform worse as well most likely

Comment: That gradient in the css is just for the blue background behind that swashy deal. It's possible that image is an html `img` or `svg`.

Comment: The css you copied is only for the background gradient, see this fiddle [http://jsfiddle.net/23Z4V/](http://jsfiddle.net/23Z4V/). They have an image with transparency overlayed on top of it (most likely).